# Infinite loop when using fscanf

Tags: c, file, infinite-loop

I wrote this simple program in C, because I'm studying FILES right now at University. I take a txt file with a list of the results of the last race so my program will show the data formatted as I want. Here's my code:

```
/* Esercizio file Motogp */
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 20

int main ()
{
    int pos, punt, num;
    float kmh;
    char nome[SIZE+1], cognome[SIZE+1], moto[SIZE+1];
    char naz[SIZE+1], nome_file[SIZE+1];

    FILE *fp;

    printf ("Inserisci il nome del file da aprire: ");
    gets (nome_file);

    fp = fopen (nome_file, "r");

    if (fopen == NULL)
        printf ("Errore nell' apertura del file %s\n", nome_file);
    else {

        while (fscanf (fp, "%d %d %d %s %s %s %s %.2f",
                &pos, &punt, &num, nome, cognome, naz, moto, &kmh) != EOF ) {

              printf ("Posizione di arrivo: %d\n", pos);
              printf ("Punteggio: %d\n", punt);
              printf ("Numero pilota: %d\n", num);
              printf ("Nome pilota: %s\n", nome);
              printf ("Cognome pilota: %s\n", cognome);
              printf ("Nazione: %s\n", naz);
              printf ("Moto: %s\n", moto);
              printf ("Media Kmh: %d\n\n", kmh);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

and there's my txt file:

```
1   25  99  Jorge LORENZO    SPA    Yamaha  164.4   
2   20  26  Dani PEDROSA     SPA    Honda   164.1   
3   16  4   Andrea DOVIZIOSO ITA    Yamaha  163.8   
4   13  1   Casey STONER     AUS    Honda   163.8   
5   11  35  Cal CRUTCHLOW    GBR    Yamaha  163.6   
6   10  19  Alvaro BAUTISTA  SPA    Honda   163.5   
7   9   46  Valentino ROSSI  ITA    Ducati  163.3   
8   8   6   Stefan BRADL     GER    Honda   162.9   
9   7   69  Nicky HAYDEN     USA    Ducati  162.5   
10  6   11  Ben SPIES    USA    Yamaha  162.3   
11  5   8   Hector BARBERA   SPA    Ducati  162.1   
12  4   17  Karel ABRAHAM    CZE    Ducati  160.9   
13  3   41  Aleix ESPARGARO  SPA    ART 160.2   
14  2   51  Michele PIRRO    ITA    FTR 160.1   
15  1   14  Randy DE PUNIET  FRA    ART 160.0   
16  0   77  James ELLISON    GBR    ART 159.9   
17  0   54  Mattia PASINI    ITA    ART 159.4   
18  0   68  Yonny HERNANDEZ  COL    BQR 159.4   
19  0   9   Danilo PETRUCCI  ITA    Ioda    158.2   
20  0   22  Ivan SILVA   SPA    BQR 158.2
```

When I run my program, it return me an infinite loop of the first one. Why?
Is there another function to read those data?

Comment: I've heard there are some situations that cause `fscanf` to never return EOF.

Comment: `fscanf` never returns EOF. It returns the number of variables read.

Comment: so how can i read the same data withou the fscanf function?

Comment: On success, the function `fscanf` returns the number of items successfully read. This count can match the expected number of readings or be less -even zero- in the case of a matching failure.
In the case of an input failure before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.

Comment: fscanf() returns the number of variables succesfully scanned OR EOF on error or EOF.

Comment: The reason you have an infinite loop is because you didn't RTFM. You will be a much more successful programmer once you realize that it is vital to read the specifications of the functions you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works (borrowed from @Mahmoud Al-Qudsi; I don't want any points for this)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 20

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int pos, punt, num;
    float kmh;
    char nome[SIZE+1], cognome[SIZE+1], moto[SIZE+1];
    char naz[SIZE+1];

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");

    if (!fp ) { printf ("Errore nell' apertura del file %s\n", argv[1]); return 0; }

        while (fscanf (fp, "%d %d %d %s %s %s %s %f\n",
                &pos, &punt, &num, nome, cognome, naz, moto, &kmh) == 8 ) {

              printf ("Posizione di arrivo: %d\n", pos);
              printf ("Punteggio: %d\n", punt);
              printf ("Numero pilota: %d\n", num);
              printf ("Nome pilota: %s\n", nome);
              printf ("Cognome pilota: %s\n", cognome);
              printf ("Nazione: %s\n", naz);
              printf ("Moto: %s\n", moto);
              printf ("Media Kmh: %f\n\n", kmh);
        }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah it works! :P sorry man i'm a student and those are my first "experiments" in programming... full of dubt and confusion!! Thank You ;)

Comment: You should realise that this is not a very robust method: once the reader gets out of sync you're lost without any hope for recovery. A real-world progam should probably read complete lines and try to extract the 8 fields from them.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are not doing any error checking. EOF is only returned at the end of file, but `fscanf` returns the number of arguments it matched otherwise, even if 0.

In your code, `fscanf` matches and reads into the variables just the first time, returning 0 thereafter. The variables then retain the original content, and you print it forever anon.

If you compiled your code with warnings, you'd see you have multiple issues:

```
test.c:23:51: warning: invalid conversion specifier '.'
      [-Wformat-invalid-specifier]
        while (fscanf (fp, "%d %d %d %s %s %s %s %.2f",
                                                ~~^
```

and

```
test.c:33:36: warning: conversion specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'double' [-Wformat]
              printf ("Media Kmh: %d\n\n", kmh);
                                  ~^       ~~~
                                  %f
```

And if you were logging or checking the return value of `fscanf`, you'd realize that you're not checking for `\n` at the end of each line. Your fprintf should (possibly) look more like this:

```
while (fscanf (fp, "%d %d %d %s %s %s %s %.2f\n",
```

Comment: Yeah :) i was not checking \n!! Thank You!!

Comment: @user and your KMH problem is that your KMH is a double and you're printing it as an int.

Comment: -1 your ending "\n" in format-string fails if the file ending without a '\n' or whitespace, a fprintf-call should ever check the return-value for scanned elements

Comment: @user411313 that's why I said "should (possibly) look...." and your last sentence makes no sense ("a .. should ever").

Comment: a whitespace before any %d is **ever** redundant, your %s fails also for input-strings separated by whitespaces

Comment: @user411313 if you're talking to me, it's not "my" %s in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You need to swallow the end-of-line character after every `fscanf` call -- e.g. at the beginning of the while block:

```
{
    fgetc(fp);
    ...
}
```

see this [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/60336) for more details (the explanation applies to any C compiler)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! The only issue i find yet is an error printing the "kmh" float variable. It should me something like "164.4" but it print to me this "2147483648"! What is wrong?

Comment: Citing Microsoft for scanf() is rather ironic: MS has a history of buggy scanf() implementations. GIYF

Comment: Edit: a better look to my result-code show a wrong result in output data... the infitine loop gone but the data shows in a strange order!